# Linq Expression returning null rather than empty set

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am finding this weird issue. When I do this >

```
activities.Where(Function(a) (Not a.IsDeleted And a.ParentId = 100)
```

It returns an in-memory query & when I try opening it up, it throws a object not set exception. This only happens when there were no items which satisfied the condition. Shouldn't it be returning an empty set?

When there **are** items satisfying the condition, then it returns a list & works all good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the lambda is being called with `a` being set to `Nothing`?

Comment: cdhowie, correct that was the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be getting bitten by using the logical `And`. You probably meant `AndAlso` to short-circuit your logical expression:

```
Not a.IsDeleted AndAlso a.ParentId = 100
```

By using `AndAlso` the second part will only be evaluated if the first part is true.